# How can I set auto height on ion-scroll with ionic?

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-directive, media-queries

I would like to know how can I set an auto-height with ion-scroll, I created a template for my modals, here is it

```
<ion-modal-view>
    <ion-content scroll="false">
        <div class="help-header header clearfix">
            content ......
        </div>

        <ion-scroll direction="y" style="height: 300px;">
            <ion-list class="item-borderless">
            <ion-item class="item-avatar">
                    <img class="image"/>
                    <p class="help-description">description
                    </p>
                </ion-item>

                <ion-item class="item-avatar">
                    <img class="image"/>
                    <p class="help-description">description
                    </p>
                </ion-item>

                <ion-item class="item-avatar">
                    <img class="image"/>
                    <p class="help-description">description
                    </p>
                </ion-item>

                 <ion-item class="item-avatar">
                    <img class="image"/>
                    <p class="help-description">description
                    </p>
                </ion-item>

                 <ion-item class="item-avatar">
                    <img class="image"/>
                    <p class="help-description">description
                    </p>
                </ion-item>

                <ion-item class="item-avatar">
                    <img class="image"/>
                    <p class="help-description">description
                    </p>
                </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
        </ion-scroll>
    </ion-content>

    <ion-footer-bar>
       footer
    </ion-footer-bar>
</ion-modal-view>
```

The content is not scrollable by-purpose that's why it is set to false. As you can see I put the height equals to 300px, the scroll behave differently from device to another which is logic as I am using px. Is there any way to make it work on all the devices, I was thinking about media queries but it's not a good solution because I need to handle all the screens. It seems that ionic v1 does not handle it automatically. Is there a directive for this?

Any help will be appreciated.

I am using ionicv1 and Angularjs and I don't support IOS devices (only Android)

Thank you.